# How do I check for string breaking characters?

Tags: lua

I'm writing an encryption algorithm for use in a game. I have most of the system done, but because of the nature of the encryption there is a chance that there will be string-breaking characters such as " and ' in the string. I want to remove these before in the encryption function before I return them, so that the decryption function does throw an error when it sees a string with a " in the middle of it.

I saw this being done in Javascript. There was a function that checked user input for characters like " in the form of:

```
string.replace("\u0022", "\"");
```

So that when the encrypted string has an unescaped quotation mark in it, it would be replaced with an escaped one.

Is it possible to do this in Lua in such a way, and if not, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't know much JavaScript, but isn't the character `\u0022` just `"`? It's better to provide an example input and expected output.

Comment: Yu Hao is right, `"\u0022"` is the unicode code point for `"`. `"\u0022" == "\""` outputs `true`.

Comment: @HelloWorld Oh, so it didn't really make sense for the guy who wrote that function to do that. I guess I can just leave the string as it is. But what about line breaks?

Comment: @latias1290: can you show an example where this is used? What do you mean with line breaks? How to replace them?

Comment: @HelloWorld I meant if having line breaks inside of a string would throw an error when it is found. Would replacing them with something like \n be a good idea, or does it not matter again? (Right now I don't really think it does, just want to be sure.)

Comment: A line break is `\n` / `\r\n`. Can you give some more information what would throw an error? Sorry, I am missing the context here.

Comment: Never mind, I did some very quick testing and I don't think it throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "string-breaking" characters in Lua, so you don't need to worry about it. If you are thinking about serializing the string and then restoring it back, then you do need to worry about correct string representation, but you can use [`%q` format character](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) that does the right thing for you:

```
('%q'):format("\r\n\"'")
```